# Is it possible to stop requireJS from adding the .js file extension automatically?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using requireJS to load scripts. It has [this detail in the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config):

> The path that is used for a module name should not include the .js
>   extension, since the path mapping could be for a directory.

In my app, I map all of my script files in a config path, because they're dynamically generated at runtime (my scripts start life as things like `order.js` but become things like `order.min.b25a571965d02d9c54871b7636ca1c5e.js` (this is a hash of the file contents, for cachebusting purposes).

In some cases, require will add a second .js extension to the end of these paths. Although I generate the dynamic paths on the server side and then populate the config path, I have to then write some extra javascript code to remove the `.js` extension from the problematic files.

Reading the requireJS docs, I really don't understand why you'd ever want the path mapping to be used for a directory. Does this mean it's possible to somehow load an entire directory's worth of files in one call? I don't get it.

Does anybody know if it's possible to just force require to stop adding .js to file paths so I don't have to hack around it?

thanks.

UPDATE: added some code samples as requested.

This is inside my HTML file (it's a Scala project so we can't write these variables directly into a `.js` file):

```
foo.js.modules = {
    order               : '@Static("javascripts/order.min.js")',
    reqwest             : 'http://5.foo.appspot.com/js/libs/reqwest',
    bean                : 'http://4.foo.appspot.com/js/libs/bean.min',
    detect              : 'order!http://4.foo.appspot.com/js/detect/detect.js',
    images              : 'order!http://4.foo.appspot.com/js/detect/images.js',
    basicTemplate       : '@Static("javascripts/libs/basicTemplate.min.js")',
    trailExpander       : '@Static("javascripts/libs/trailExpander.min.js")',
    fetchDiscussion     : '@Static("javascripts/libs/fetchDiscussion.min.js")'
    mostPopular         : '@Static("javascripts/libs/mostPopular.min.js")'
};
```

Then inside my `main.js`:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: foo.js.modules
});

require([foo.js.modules.detect, foo.js.modules.images, "bean"], 
    function(detect, images, bean) {
        // do stuff
});
```

In the example above, I have to use the string "bean" (which refers to the require path) rather than my direct object (like the others use `foo.js.modules.bar`) otherwise I get the extra `.js` appended.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you include an example of your require function call?
Are you using require.config()? What are your settings?

Comment: Thanks - have added some code above. Using require.config() just to push the paths into require.

Comment: the variable bean isn't going to resolve to anything (without quotes). You'd have to use the full foo.js.modules.bean reference. Personally, I use the quoted form, so I'm not sure what to expect otherwise.

Comment: Not sure I follow -- I *am* using it with quotes, apart from in the callback arguments but I don't want it to be a string there. When I use foo.js.modules.bean it adds the extra '.js' extension.

Comment: I see now. This could perhaps be considered a bug, but I ALWAYS omit ".js" from ALL entries in requirejs.config -> paths. If you do so, you should be able to use either the foo.js.modules.ID reference, or the string "ID", **however** you might have problems depending on how the module itself is exported. For instance, I wasn't able to use the **reference** approach to import jQuery because jQuery exports itself under the id "jquery" but requirejs didn't know to match that up to the "js/lib/jquery-1.7.1" entry I had under paths.

Comment: Note, all my other modules work like the following example and export just fine:
define ([], function () {   
 var Bob = function (){}
 return Bob 
})

Answer (score 14, accepted):

requirejs' [noext plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins):

> Load scripts without appending ".js" extension, useful for dynamic scripts...
>
> #### Documentation
>
> check the `examples` folder. All the info you probably need will be inside comments or on the example code itself.
>
> #### Basic usage
>
> Put the plugins inside the `baseUrl` folder (usually same folder as the main.js file) or create an alias to the plugin location:
>
> ```
> require.config({
>     paths : {
>         //create alias to plugins (not needed if plugins are on the baseUrl)
>         async: 'lib/require/async',
>         font: 'lib/require/font',
>         goog: 'lib/require/goog',
>         image: 'lib/require/image',
>         json: 'lib/require/json',
>         noext: 'lib/require/noext',
>         mdown: 'lib/require/mdown',
>         propertyParser : 'lib/require/propertyParser',
>         markdownConverter : 'lib/Markdown.Converter'
>     }
> });
>
> //use plugins as if they were at baseUrl
> define([
>         'image!awsum.jpg',
>         'json!data/foo.json',
>         'noext!js/bar.php',
>         'mdown!data/lorem_ipsum.md',
>         'async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',
>         'goog!visualization,1,packages:[corechart,geochart]',
>         'goog!search,1',
>         'font!google,families:[Tangerine,Cantarell]'
>     ], function(awsum, foo, bar, loremIpsum){
>         //all dependencies are loaded (including gmaps and other google apis)
>     }
> );
> ```

Answer (score 118):

If you don't feel like adding a dependency on noext, you can also just append a dummy query string to the path to prevent the .js extension from being appended, as in:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'signalr-hubs': '/signalr/hubs?noext'
    }
});
```

This is what the noext plugin does.

Comment: Much the better solution IMO, you don't need to add yet another library into the load. Just six extra characters in the config.

Comment: Agreed - this is far simpler. Also happened to be the exact example I was looking for (SignalR). Thank you!

Comment: Does somebody have an idea why we cannot have option inside config?

Comment: im having this similar issue, so i was trying out your sol..can i just include the above path in the config, w/o having adding the noext plugin..and also where do i refere 'signalr-hubs' in?

Comment: Is there a rule somewhere that a config path with _any_ query string does not get `.js` appended?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone No. How this works is `?noext` becomes `?noext.js`, which still acts as a dummy query string.

Comment: It worked even only put `?` at the end, instead of `?noext`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using requirejs server side with node.js. The noext plugin does not work for me. I suspect this is because it tries to add ?noext to a url and we have filenames instead of urls serverside.

I need to name my files .njs or .model to separate them from static .js files. Hopefully the author will update requirejs to not force automatic .js file extension conventions on the users.

Meanwhile here is a quick patch to disable this behavior.

To apply this patch (against version 2.1.15 of node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js) :

1. Save in a file called disableAutoExt.diff or whatever and open a terminal
2. cd path/to/node_modules/
3. patch -p1 < path/to/disableAutoExt.diff
4. add disableAutoExt: true, to your requirejs.config: requirejs.config({disableAutoExt: true,});

Now we can do require(["test/index.njs", ...] ... and get back to work.

Save this patch in disableAutoExt.diff :

```
--- mod/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js 2014-09-07 20:54:07.000000000 -0400
+++ node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js 2014-12-11 09:33:21.000000000 -0500
@@ -1884,6 +1884,10 @@
         //Delegates to req.load. Broken out as a separate function to
         //allow overriding in the optimizer.
         load: function (id, url) {
+            if (config.disableAutoExt && url.match(/\..*\.js$/)) {
+                url = url.replace(/\.js$/, '');
+            }
+
             req.load(context, id, url);
         },
```

The patch simply adds the following around line 1887 to node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:

```
if (config.disableAutoExt && url.match(/\..*\.js$/)) {
    url = url.replace(/\.js$/, '');
}
```

UPDATE: Improved patch by moving url change deeper in the code so it no longer causes a hang after calling undef on a module. Needed undef because:

To disable caching of modules when developing with node.js add this to your main app file:

```
requirejs.onResourceLoad = function(context, map)
{
    requirejs.undef(map.name);
};
```