# Overcoming RequireJS's '.js' extension adding in cache/proxy environments

Tags: requirejs

RequireJS automatically adds a '.js' extension to each module name, and a known hack is to add a `?` at the end, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15392880/290343) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20100613/290343).

The problem is, that adding a question mark means cache and proxy servers will usually conclude these are dynamic files and not cache them. I guess it's configurable if I control these cache/proxy servers but between my server and the client there is potentially a downstream of proxy servers in between which is beyond my control.

So, is there any other way to cause RequireJS to not add the `.js` extension *other than* putting a question mark?

Comment: Maybe i am wrong but GET requests with same params should be cached by proxies.

Comment: @ant_Ti: _"Most proxies, most notably Squid up through version 3.0, do not cache resources with a "?" in their URL."_ - https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to configure require.js to achieve what you want. But you can override `require.load` method and make url preprocessing

```js
require.load = (function(load) {
    var stripJSRegex = /\.js$/;

    return function(context, moduleName, url) {
        load.call(this, context, moduleName, url.replace(stripJSRegex, ''));
    }
})(require.load);
```