# Frontend caching requirejs on nodejs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, requirejs, asset-pipeline

I am trying to implement fingerprinting in my node.js server
I am using requirejs and my main page loads the scripts like this:

```
<script src="/public/assets2/scripts/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="/public/assets2/scripts/app/common.js"></script>
<script>
 require.config({baseUrl: '/public/assets2/scripts/lib'});
 require(['app/main']);
</script>
```

Assets are built into `public/assets2` directory. On a rebuild, I want
to change the requirejs config `baseUrl` to the hashed version
`public/assets2/HASHHASH`.  So requirejs will request the scripts like
this: `public/assets2/HASHHASH/scripts/app.main.js`

Is it a good idea to add the hash to the baseUrl like that? I think
this is recommended approach if i understand correctly.

Assets are still built into `public/assets2` and not in
`public/assets2/HASHHASH`, so i need to make a mapping between these
two, or actually place the assets into `HASHASH` directory. Is there a
nice library already does this, how can i simply implement this?

## EDIT

borschik is great, but requirejs already copies all my assets into
build folder where it can request them later. borchik is an overkill
with requirejs. But again, requirejs has no built-in solution for
cache busting. From what i understand here: , it is recommended
that i place all the assets in a versioned folder, and fix my baseUrl
accordingly. This is the simplest fix for requirejs, and i don't even
need to generate hashes from files, i will generate just one hash
everytime build task is run.

The problem i have is step 3.

> 3 . Configure your webserver (nginx etc.) to return original file
>   even if you requested it with hash

I am asking for a convenient way to do this on nodejs.

Example:

GET `public/assets2/<hash>/app/main.js`

Strip hash and return
`public/assets2/app/main.js`

The other problem is every asset is busted even if i only change one
file. So i guess ultimate solution would be to build this into
requirejs.

r.js will copy all the assets with hashed counterparts on
optimization. Then on browser it will request the hashed file urls.
This will require a manifest file, between optimization tool and
requirejs on browser.

Comment: Well, if you want to process files' hashmap on client side then maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24680885/896280) will help you.

Comment: @ant_Ti still r.js needs to build the files with hashed names. then it needs to produce a manifest file to do the mapping. then i can override the load method. or even better i can pass a manifest option to requirejs config so it does it for me!

Comment: You can build manifest with [grunt-frontend](https://github.com/sergeche/grunt-frontend) task

Comment: @ant_Ti that means double configuration for files, i need grunt-frontend functionality built into requirejs.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [borschik](https://www.npmjs.org/package/borschik) especially at its [freeze and resource inlining](https://github.com/bem/borschik/blob/master/docs/freeze/freeze.en.md) ability.

If borschik isn't suits you well then here is some theory on how can you implement such mechanism:

1. Firstly you need to use [grunt-frontend](https://github.com/sergeche/grunt-frontend) task to generate files' hashes. Later you will use them for creating urls with hashes.
2. Create simple method that will take path to file as argument and search in `.build-catalog.json` created by `grunt-frontend` to create and return hash specific url.
3. Configure your webserver (nginx etc.) to return original file even if you requested it with hash
4. Set all path using your method written in 2nd step

   ```
   require.config({
       path: {
           lib: requireURL('/public/assets2/scripts/lib.js') // Will result in: "/public/assets2/<hash>/scripts/lib"
       }
   });
   ```

But there is a limitation. `grunt-frontend` can only calculate hashes from files and not folders. You can't set `baseUrl: requireURL('/public/assets2/scripts/lib')` because then all files will be required with same hash.

But there is a workaround for folders. You can request url for file and strip result to folder you interested in. But keep in mind that folder hash will change on file change.

---

In addition to this scheme you can configure file sharding to improve parallel resource loading in browsers